# jQuery create <td> element with href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using this piece of code:

```
for (var website in response) {
    var row = $('<tr class="odd gradeX"/>');
    $('<td/>', { text: response[website]['website_name'] }).appendTo(row);
    row.appendTo(tBody);
}
```

No i want the `td` to link to `/website?id=` where id should be equal to `response[website]` . What will be the shortest way to achieve that?

to make it clearer . if currently the result of `$('<td/>', { text: response[website]['website_name']` is:
`<td>siteName</td>` and the value inside `response[website]` is 2 for example than i want to create an element looking like this:

`<td><a href="/website?id=2">siteName</a></td>`.

note: i'm looking for the shortest best way. not necessarily one line solution.

Comment: I'm little confused of what you are asking. Can you clarify?

Comment: sure ill update my post

Comment: Why does it need to be one line? Brevity can be beautiful unless your colleagues can't read it, and know where you live.

Comment: i am wondering how `response[website] = 2` and `response[website]['website_name'] = siteName`. could you please share this JS object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create the `td` and `a` in a similar way to what you already have:

```
for (var website in response) {
    var row = $('<tr class="odd gradeX"/>');
    var cell = $('<td/>');

    $('<a/>', { href: '/website?id=' +  response[website], text: response[website]['website_name'] })
              .appendTo(cell);
    cell.appendTo(row);
    row.appendTo(tBody);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create a html string and then just use `$.append` to insert element.

```js
var response={test:{website_name:"Test Website",id:2},foo:{website_name:"foo",id:3},bar:{website_name:"Bar Website",id:4}};

for (var website in response) {
  var _html = `<tr class="odd gradeX"><td><a href="/website?id=${response[website]['id']}">${response[website]['website_name']}</a></td></tr>`
  $('#table tbody').append(_html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:** string template is not supported in all browsers. For that you can use normal string concatenation to create HTML string.

Answer (score -2):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
for (var website in response) {
    var row = $('<tr class="odd gradeX"/>');
    $('<td><a id="'+response[website]+'" href="#">'+response[website]["website_name"]+'</a></td>').appendTo(row);');
    row.appendTo(tBody);
}
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```